# In bplain \`{} is combined with next character when using font \tt

Tags: plain-tex

With plain TeX e.g.

```
{\tt\char`\\\`{}\char`\{\char`\}}
```

does display

```
\`{}
```

as expected. With bplain format the grave accent and the left brace is combined.

Why bplain differs here?

How can a grave accent be printed in bplain with font \tt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a crucial difference: plain TeX defines `` \` `` as

```
\def\`#1{{\accent18 #1}}
```

whereas `` \show\` `` with `bplain.tex` gives

```
> \`=macro:
->\OT1-cmd \`\OT1\` .
```

and `` \expandafter\show\csname OT1\string\`\endcsname `` produces

```
> \OT1\`=\long macro:
#1->\accent 18 #1.
```

The missing braces are the culprit; with plain TeX definition, the closing brace makes `\accent` to become `\char`, but in the `bplain` definition, the next token becomes the accentee.

Solution. Either give a more sensible definition

```
\expandafter\def\csname OT1\string\`\endcsname#1{{\accent 18 #1}}
```

or simply define

```
\chardef\textgraveaccent=18
```

and do

```
{\tt\char`\\\textgraveaccent\char`\{\char`\}}
```